# Crop image from gallery (Editing is not supported for this image)

Tags: android, gallery, crop

Get image from gallery

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

after startActivityForResult();

```
//try - Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT); - doesn't work too

Intent editImageIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

editImageIntent.setType("image/*");
editImageIntent.setData(result.getData());

editImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
editImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
editImageIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
editImageIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
editImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
editImageIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
editImageIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);                   
editImageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
editImageIntent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
editImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPath);

startActivityForResult(editImageIntent, CROP);
```

When start this intent

> Editing is not supported for this image

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll try to use lib =)